# select millions records from table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have more than 7 000 000 record in my temp table 
and I want to select all record less than 3 minutes.

My query is

```
SELECT referrals.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Donorid ORDER BY startdate asc ) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM #tempReferrals as referrals
WHERE referrals.startdate  IS NOT NULL
```

Otherwise I want to access only

```
SELECT id
FROM #tempReferrals WITH (NOLOCK)
```

So where take more than 5 minutes. Please give me any solution.
Also I have index id in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure have enough memory in your server to keep your temp table and the result table in main memory at the same time. As soon as the instance needs to start moving data to hard disk you will have trouble keeping your time constraints.